# Clique em link funciona só no padding HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, link, padding

Tenho uma navbar e os links nela, só funcionam se eu clicar onde fica o *padding* deles. Alguém sabe a causa, e se possível, uma solução para o problema?

[image]

PS: Uso o materialize.

```
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="perto_de_mim.php" class="black-text tooltipped" data-tooltip="O que há perto de mim?"><i class="material-icons">room</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="paginadebusca.php" class="black-text tooltipped" data-tooltip="Melhores ofertas no momento"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="black-text dropdown-button tooltipped" data-tooltip="Menu" data-activates="dropdown1"><i class="material-icons">view_headline</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php" class="black-text tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Home"><i class="material-icons" >home</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: experimenta adicionar um `display:block;` externo a ver o que acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser algo relacionado ao seu código css. Uma possibilidade é que a imagem dos ícones que está utilizando na sua navbar estão "sobrepondo" o lugar onde os links funcionariam. Não sei se colocou tais imagens como background. Caso não tenha, vale a pena tentar. E caso não resolva, facilitaria colocar o código css tbm =)

Comment: As imagens são "material-icons" então não acho q dê pra colocar em background. E os links são os icones. E o css, está dentro do materialize, q é um arquivo consideravelmente grande.

Comment: Tenta assim
https://jsfiddle.net/3L40bvyt/

Comment: Não funcionou desse jeito. Todos os ícones juntaram num único canto. Eu consegui fazer com que funcionasse, tirando uma classe que estava por engano. Porém, o dropdown ainda não funciona. (O botão do dropdown é o que está marcado na imagem). Nele, ainda é necessário clicar no espaço do padding.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar colocar cada tag `<a>` por fora da tag `<li>`, assim:

```
<a href="#" class="black-text dropdown-button tooltipped" data-tooltip="Menu" data-activates="dropdown1"><li><i class="material-icons">view_headline</i></li></a>
```

Apesar de não ser considerado o ideal (o mais elegante seria manter o HTML da forma que está e consertar o css), pode ser que funcione para seu caso pois vai forçar com que o link ocupe todo o espaço do li.

Obs: Não conheço o `materialize`

Comment: Não deu certo :(   Acho q não tem como. Porque na própria documentação, não tem como abrir o menu clicando no icone, só no texto. Veja: http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#navbar-dropdown

Comment: Verdade, este é o funcionamento padrão no `materialize`, é péssimo para a UX pois justamente na ícone de seta para baixo o clique não funciona ;/